# Using GMM (Generalized Method of Moments) with 3rd and 4th order moments (skew and kurt)

Tags: statistics

I'd like to solve a GMM model with third-order and fourth-order moments for unknown (non-normal) distribution, i.e., get the asymptotic distribution of a vector theta consisting of the parameters that describe the unknown non-normal distribution.
How can this be done?
Thanks
Roy